# Binding inside of a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

Ok I have a Observable collection containing string defined like so.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> OCGroundType { get; set; }
```

This collection is having resources key so what I'm trying to do is with this code

```
            <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="110" Margin="156,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=OCGroundType}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

So what I'm trying to do is give the path the value of the itemsource is that possible?

***Edit***

That's what the staticresource is 'binded' to , a resourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cultures="clr-namespace:Marcam.Cultures"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Marcam.Properties">

   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What the ObjectType is 'binded' to is a method who return the current Resources.resx, If I've understanded well how it's work because I've based this code on this [WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because a `Binding` is not a `DependencyObject`, so its properties cannot be bound.

However, you could achieve the desired result by using a converter that fetches the appropriate value from the resources.

---

EDIT: first, you need a converter like this:

```
public class ResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string key = (string)value;
        return Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(key, culture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then, declare an instance of this converter in the XAML resources:

```
<local:ResourceConverter x:Key="resourceConverter" />
```

And finally, just use this converter in your binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource resourceConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Ahumm I could use more than a single bone ^^''. I'm new to wpf, could you point me in a somehow more specific direction ?? Because I've never used a 'converter'

Comment: Basicly what the current binding do is get a key, (defined by me) from the Observable Collection and this key is the same in the resources dictionary so I'm trying to get the get from the OC and use it to bind  the value

Comment: @Mokmeuh, what does `{StaticResource Resources}` refer to in your code? What is the type of the resource named `Resources`?

Comment: Ok I see now, but using this will not bind to the Resource dictionary ? It would bind to the datacontext right ? wich is pointing to itself, but if I add the source it should work ??, Let me test it

Comment: I defined this `<cultures:ResourceConverter x:Key="resourceConverter"/>` in my resourceDictionary and it's not working (yes I,ve created the class) it's compiling and everythings but it don't show the data in the listbox

Comment: I've, by error, clicked on the listbox and it seems the object are there but invisible, they are selectionable but it doesn't have any content

Comment: @Mokmeuh, try to put a breakpoint in the Convert method to see what's happening

Comment: I've put a `console.writeLine(key);` and it seems to get all the value  because he's printing them in the console but with the converter I can't get it work and If I remove the converter it's showing what is inside the collection

Comment: @Mokmeuh, what does ResourceManager.GetObject return when you debug the converter?

Comment: Apparently blank space as if the key was not found, After trying to do a ToString() and getting a NullReferenceException I would say it's returning nothing

Comment: But I've put a break and the ResourceManager is pointing to the Properties folder but my resources are in another namespace that's why I'm using a resourceDictionary to get the right .resx

Comment: @Mokmeuh, just replace Properties.Resources with the appropriate name to use the right resx file

Comment: I can't access `FindResource()` in the ResourceConverter

Comment: @Mokmeuh, what FindResource are you talking about? Just refer to the class the wraps the resx file

Comment: The method `GetResourceInstance` of the class `CultureResources` is not static and it's returning a new instance of `Cultures.Resources()` but with the ResourceDictionary, wich is using the method, is already initialized and it's using the key word `Resources` so I'm trying to access this key by using `FindResource()` but the method is not recognized.

Comment: That would be the source properties `Application.Current.Resources.FindName("Resources")` be equals to, but this is returning a Resource.resx I guess

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49189/discussion-between-mokmeuh-and-thomas-levesque)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Resources are mere string values declared under resources section of Window or UserControl, you can achieve that using `IMultiValueConverter`.

**First** of all you need to pass `resource key` and second `ResourceDictionary` of Window/UserControl wherever your resources are defined.

XAML will look like this:

```
<Label>
  <Label.Content>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceToValueConverter}">
       <Binding/>
       <Binding Path="Resources" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource
                               Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Ofcourse you need to add instance of `ResourceToValueConverter` in XAML.

**Second** here goes your converter code:

```
public class ResourceToValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((ResourceDictionary)values[1])[values[0]];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, 
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As you edited the question to include that resource is `ObjectDataProvider`, you can modify converter code.

You have `ObjectDataProvider` in your converter which you can get and call it's method to get the resource file(.resx) file. Get string value from the resource file and return it.

```
var provider = ((ResourceDictionary)values[1])["Resources"] as ObjectDataProvider;
var output = provider.Data;
return // Get string from resource file and return it.
```

Comment: Using this will not use the ObjectDataProvider so when I change localization it will not update the value or I'm wrong xD

Comment: @Mokmeuh - I have updated the answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to get the value from the key with the output, it's an object of what type ?

Comment: And the provider is returning a nullexception :S

Comment: You need to do `((ResourceDictionary)values[1])["Resources"] as ObjectDataProvider;` to get `ObjectDataProvider`. Output will be return type of your method `GetResourceInstance`.